# Is my database rational correct? one Primary key to Multiple foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, database, one-to-many

I have an idea that I want to execute and am very rusty on my database design when it comes to the relationships between tables. I want to be able to type in 3 ingredients into 3 `<input type="text">` fields and search for all the recipes with those ingredients.

I have 3 tables...

- ingredients
- recipe
- menu

the columns that are bold are my primary keys and i want the columns in italics to be the foreign keys.

Example - iName is the primary key to iName1 iName2 and iName3.

---

## INGREDIENTS

**iName** - iType

## RECIPE

**mName** - *iName1* - *iName2* - *iName3* - method

## MENU

*mName* - mDiscription - mAllergy

---

Are the relationships between my tables efficient enough for what I want to do? and what would the join query be if I want to for example

```
SELECT mName, mDiscripton, mAllergy
FROM menu
WHERE iName1 = input etc etc
```

I already have a one table version of the database and the query I'm using works fine; I just want to redesign my database and modify my query to suit.

Comment: Spelling: `mDiscripton` should be `mDescription`, and in general table prefixes in columns (imo) don't tend to be used these days, and neither does mixed case. `menu.description` is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use 1..n colums to save a n..m connection between two tables.

As you can use one ingredient in different recipes, you will need a matching table.
Those are often called table1_2_table2, or in your case recipe2ingredient.
In there you store the primary keys from both tables (in most cases as a combined primary key on that table, as it often makes sense)

The same should go for menu and recipe, since you could want to use a recipe in several menus.

So

```
Table 1 - Menu    (ID, Name, ... whatever columns you need on top of that)
Table 2 - Recipe (ID, Name, ...whatever columns you could desire)
Table 3 - Menu2Recipe( IdMenu, IdRecipe)
Table 4 - Ingredient (ID, Name, measurement unit)
Table 5 - Ingredient2Recipe( IdRecipe, IdIngredient, Amount )
```

Comment: ok i think i know what you mean, instead of having my primary keys in ingredients and recipe create a table that has the primary keys for both, same with recipe and ingredient. i dont fully understand what the relationships are, and does this account for multiple ingredients in one recipe?? sorry for the amateur questions but ive been wrecking my brain over this for a while.

Comment: thats not an amateur question, its good that you ask. Instead of having the ingeredients stored in columns within one table, you simply enter them into rows. That said you have the `Recipe A` and `Ingredient 1, 2, 3`. If you need 1 and 3 for Recipe A you will have 2 Rows in Ingredient2Recipe-Table with `A,1` and `A,3` as the colum values (foreign keys to the original tables via the primary key). If Recipe B would require all 3 existing ingredients the table would simply hold `B,1`, `B,2`, `B,3` . that way you do not need to know/limit the max. amount of ingredients.

Comment: ok that helps a bit, so my ingredients table will basically have all ingredients needed for all recipes (what i always assumed) Say i want to see recipe D which has ingredients 1, 20 and 35. would that mean that the ingredient2Recipe table will have 3 rows e.g D1, D20 and D35. D being the ID of the meal name and the numbers (1, 20, 35) being the IDs of the ingredients? I think this is helping me understand but cant see my way through to the end, how would the query work if i want to search for a meal with 3 ingredients?

SELECT name, description FROM menu WHERE

and this is where i get lost

Comment: Your assumption with D1, D20 and D35 is correct. Searching for a meal "having" exactly three ingredients is easy speaking from an SQL point of view, it is done by GROUPING ( see W3 for a tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp and follow to "having" ). Since you should/will store the ingredients in another table this will be most likely done by a grouped join : `SELECT r.name, COUNT(ir.*) FROM recipe r, ingredients2recipe ir WHERE ir.recipeId = r.id GROUP BY ir.recipeId HAVING COUNT(ir.*) = 3`

Answer (score 0):

Your design is missing one table to be efficient; remove iName1 to iName3 from your recipe table and add a mapping table "recipe_ingredients" with foreign keys for recipe and one ingredient. You will then have one to many rows in that table for every recipe (look at my example). But: You can easily search for all recipes where an ingredient is used. And you can use 10000 ingredients for one recipe if necessary.

How is the table menu related to recipes? Does a menu always consist of one recipe? Otherwise also add a mapping table for that relation.

```
SELECT mName, mDiscription, mAllergy 
    FROM menu
        JOIN recipe ON recipe.mName = menu.mName
        JOIN recipe_ingredients ON recipe_ingredients.mName = recipe.mName
    WHERE recipe_ingredients.iName = 'whatever'
```

Comment: well i want each row in menu to correspond to a row in recipe, i.e each meal in menu will have its own recipe. as i'm more of a web "designer" than a "developer" and im not very efficient when it comes to coding php (mySQL), javascript and im still a little in the dark about how the relationships between the tables (should) work :(